# React - Javascript Variable Scoping Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, scope

I am creating a questionnaire using React. At the beginning of my component, `QuestionnaireForm`, I define `applicableCriteria` to be a list of all applicable criteria. As different questions are answered in the questionnaire, criteria are added or removed based on a JSON file I am using to serve as the back end. The only problem is that when I try to edit `applicableCriteria` within my function, it is not updating the `var applicableCriteria` variable I defined outside the function. I know this by inspecting the contents within the `applicableCriteria` variable, so it must be an issue with scope.

I'm not very experienced with JavaScript and React, so I am unsure of how to best deal with this. This is a slightly more complex scenario since the function containing `applicableCriteria` is called by another function, so I can't just set it equal for assignment. Is there another way? Thank you.

```
const QuestionnaireForm = () => {

  var applicableCriteria = [];
  // Push all possible criteria to list
  for (let q = 0; q < Records.length; q++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < Records[q].criterion.length; c++) {
      applicableCriteria.push(Records[q].criterion[c]);
    }
  }

  const data = useRef();
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(data.current.value, "initialvalue");
    localStorage.setItem("inputValue", data.current.value);
  };

  const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage("name", "");

  function arrayHandler(id, decision, criterionList) {
    var decisionSignal;
    if (decision == true) {
      decisionSignal = "No";
    } else {
      decisionSignal = "Yes";
    }
    var criteriaOfInterest = Records[id].criterion;

    if (decisionSignal == Records[id].decision) {
      for (let i = 0; i < criteriaOfInterest.length; i++) {
        const index = criterionList.indexOf(criteriaOfInterest[i]);
        const x = criterionList.splice(index, 1);
      }
      console.log(criterionList.length);
    } else if (decisionSignal !== Records[id].decision) {
      for (let i = 0; i < criteriaOfInterest.length; i++) {
        criterionList.indexOf(criteriaOfInterest[i]) === -1
          ? criterionList.push(criteriaOfInterest[i])
          : console.log("this item already exists");
      }
    }

    console.log(applicableCriteria.length);

    return criterionList;
  }

  const [checked0, setChecked0] = React.useState(false);
  const handleChange0 = () => {
    setChecked0(!checked0);
    console.log(checked0);
    applicableCriteria = arrayHandler(0, checked0, applicableCriteria);
  };

  const [checked1, setChecked1] = React.useState(false);
  const handleChange1 = () => {
    setChecked1(!checked1);
    console.log(checked1);
    applicableCriteria = arrayHandler(1, checked1, applicableCriteria);
  };

  const [checked2, setChecked2] = React.useState(false);
  const handleChange2 = () => {
    setChecked2(!checked2);
    console.log(checked2);
    applicableCriteria = arrayHandler(2, checked2, applicableCriteria);
  };

  const [checked3, setChecked3] = React.useState(false);
  const handleChange3 = () => {
    setChecked3(!checked3);
    console.log(checked3);
    applicableCriteria = arrayHandler(3, checked3, applicableCriteria);
  };

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("Submitted");
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App__form">
      <h1> Questionnaire </h1>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Checkbox
          label={Records[0].question}
          value={checked0}
          onChange={handleChange0}
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <Checkbox
          label={Records[1].question}
          value={checked1}
          onChange={handleChange1}
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <Checkbox
          label={Records[2].question}
          value={checked2}
          onChange={handleChange2}
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <Checkbox
          label={Records[3].question}
          value={checked3}
          onChange={handleChange3}
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

// Checkbox Component
const Checkbox = ({ label, value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={value} onChange={onChange} />
      {label}
    </label>
  );
};

export default QuestionnaireForm;
```

Comment: Can you clarify how specifically you're observing that this is a *scope* issue, and reduce the code shown to *only* a [mcve]?  It's pretty strange that `applicableCriteria` isn't a state value, and as currently defined it will be reset to its initial value on every render.  So any edits you make to it will be lost any time the component re-renders.